# Get year,month and day from python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, variables

I'd like to get the break of a variable by year, month and day. Here's what I got:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
print (yesterday)
year = datetime.date.yesterday.year
month = datetime.date.yesterday.month
day=datetime.date.yesterday.day
print (year)
print (month)
print (day)
```

I'm getting an error that datetime.date has no attribute. I'm a total noob at python and I'm stuck, any help is appreciated

Comment: just a note, I know I don't need the 'print (yesterday)' line, it was just testing for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you were close

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
print (yesterday)
year = yesterday.year
month = yesterday.month
day=yesterday.day
print (year)
print (month)
print (day)
```

result is

2019-03-10

2019

3

10

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strftime` method

A simple example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.utcnow()
>>> year_month_day_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
>>> now.strftime(year_month_day_format)
'2020-11-06'
>>> hour_minute_format = '%H:%M'
>>> now.strftime(hour_minute_format)
'22:54'
```

Hopping, it will help someones

Answer (score 2):

You can also simplify your import statements like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(1)

print(yesterday)

year = yesterday.year
month = yesterday.month
day = yesterday.day

print(year)
print(month)
print(day)
```

You will get the output:

```
2019-03-10 21:19:36.695577
2019
3
10
```

Comment: this works, Baris just beat you, thanks for the simplifying tip

Comment: That's how it is ;)... I will point out however that `yesterday` will also contain the time as shown in the output I added. From there, you can also access other attributes such as `yesterday.hour`, `yesterday.microsecond`, `yesterday.minute`, `yesterday.second` or even split individual fractions of time with `yesterday.time()` and get the digit that corresponds to the day of the week with `yesterday.weekday()`.

Comment: you could also strip the time information using -- yesterday.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

Answer (score 1):

For current day

```
import datetime

current_datetime=datetime.datetime.now()
print("current_year:{}".format(current_datetime.year))
print("current_month:{}".format(current_datetime.month))
print("current_day:{}".format(current_datetime.day))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want in this format for example "10-Oct-2018". You can try this code for current day.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
year = now_utc.strftime("%Y")
month = now_utc.strftime("%b")
day = now_utc.strftime("%d")
result = day+"-"+month+"-"+year

print(result)
```